# Select specific days from a Spatraster using terra package

Tags: r, subset, r-raster, terra

I want to subset a SpatRaster, using the terra package,  by selecting only the days where the raster values are greater than a specific threshold. I remade my code by generating a SpatRaster with 3 layers (my original raster is a temporal one). Unfortunately, I have this error:[subset] no (valid) layer selected. However, I also tried with subset() function, the same error.

```
library(terra)

d <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr = 3)
values(d[[1]]) <- 50:ncell(d)
values(d[[2]]) <- 60:ncell(d)
values(d[[3]]) <- 70:ncell(d)

set.seed(0)
d <- d[[d>60]]## error [subset] no (valid) layer selected
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
d <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr = 10, vals=1:1000)
time(d) <- as.Date("2001-12-31") + 1:10
```

Subset based on time stamp values.

```
d[[time(d) > as.Date("2002-01-05")]]
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 5  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : lyr.6, lyr.7, lyr.8, lyr.9, lyr.10 
#min values  :   501,   601,   701,   801,    901 
#max values  :   600,   700,   800,   900,   1000 
#time (days) : 2002-01-06 to 2002-01-10
```

Or

```
subset(d, time(d) > as.Date("2002-01-05"))
```

To select layers based on some statistic such as their maximum value you can first compute the statistic and then subset.

```
g <- global(d, max, na.rm=T)
subset(d, g$max > 500)

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 5  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : lyr.6, lyr.7, lyr.8, lyr.9, lyr.10 
#min values  :   501,   601,   701,   801,    901 
#max values  :   600,   700,   800,   900,   1000 
#time (days) : 2002-01-06 to 2002-01-10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my question was how I can subset based on the values of the raster, not based on time. For example, selecting only the days(the layers) where I only have values greater than 10. Meaning that from 10 layers, only 4 layers have values greater than 10. So how do I select those 4 layers (days, in my case)? Sorry if I wasn't clear in my previous question.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to cover that